# How to properly configure the connection of .css files to .html.erb files if i have 2 controllers. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For exemple, i have something contoller_1 with index.html.irb, and i have something controller_2 with index2.html.irb, how to properly connect .css files to this html-documents. I want to connect separate files to index.html.irb (for exemple, index.css) and to index2.html.irb (for exemple, index2.css).
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use all stylesheets with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

...or you may create a separate directory that will use your external stylesheet

asset::your_external_css::new_sytle

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "your_external_css/new_style" %>
```

found in (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)